# Why is 'the' before winter season?

Tags: articles

In my opinion, 'the' is a definite article. It emphasis saying "that one only".
Why then 'the' before winter season. There is only one kind of winter season. There cannot be different kind of winter season. For example, the food means that specific food, food - means general. The winter seasons means specific, whereas winter season is not specific, it is general only. I am confused here because someone has corrected me to use the before winter season. Please help.

Comment: It all depends on context.  Can you tell us the sentence you have questions on? Also, you may be interested in http://ell.stackexchange.com/ which may be more suitable for this question.

Comment: "In my opinion, 'the' is a definite article"? *The* is a definite article by definition. You don't need to have an opinion on it, and even if you do it does not matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than seeing the definite article in this usage as indicating a particular winter, I see it as (at least usually) referencing the particular season that is winter.

The hunting season. The holiday season (is when most hoteliers make their money).

The diesel locomotive (can mean 'as opposed to the horse, the electric 'locomotive', the steam locomotive – ie a particular type of motive power – **or** 'the actual piece of metal I'm talking about').

The floribunda rose (was introduced by the Danish breeder Dines Poulsen in 1907).

Answer (score 3):

This is not a question of semantics, but of syntax.

The word *season* does not fall in any of the classes of noun which can be used without an determiner (plurals, mass nouns, proper nouns) and so requires a determiner (an article, a demonstrative, a possessive, a quantifier etc). Having a modifier such as *Winter* before it makes no difference.

*Winter* itself is different, having some of the characteristics of a proper noun (not all of them: it may take *the*, whereas typical proper nouns don't).

Comment: So why do we not use 'the' in front of 'hospital' as do the Americans? Does that have 'characteristics of a proper noun'? See my exchange below with Kristina Lopez.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that analysis before, but yes, I think _hospital_ etc is a quasi-proper noun. Note that it can't be pluralised or even modified; and that it has a particular meaning: _in hospital_ means _as a patient_, not just visiting. I think it's only _hospital_ where we differ from the Americans. We agree about _college_, _jail_ and _school_ (though we say _at school_ and they say _in school_).

Comment: @ Colin Fine  I think the same applies to 'university'. Yes, it is interesting that, in the UK, doctors and nurses work in a/the hospital, but only patients are 'in hospital'. Similarly lecturers teach at a/the university but students go 'to university'. It is almost as though the term 'in hospital' is a sort of compound adjective describing a state of being of the individual; similarly being 'at university' as regards a student.

Comment: Also, of course, only prisoners are 'in jail/prison' The prison officers work 'at the prison'. But as you have noted this form is accepted by Americans too.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is used to describe a particular *instance* of the season, rather than a particular type of season:

> The squirrel here is collecting nuts in preparation for the winter.

In this context, "the winter" means the (unique) next winter season.

There are multiple instances of winter occurring, so the is justified. The indefinite article can also be used in such phrases as:

> The crops were ruined by a particularly bitter winter.

Comment: In this instance, it is worth pointing out that you could (in Queen's English) dispense with the definite article and say 'The squirrel is collecting nuts in preparation for winter'. (Americans may disagree)  But if you used 'winter season' it would require a 'the' in front of it. This is for the reason to which you refer in your question. Winter is a recurring event. Whereas the next 'winter season' is something more specific. It must seem confusing!

Comment: @WS2, not sure why you'd think that but Americans agree that 'in preparation for winter' is acceptable. :-)

Comment: @Kristina Lopez  Sorry if I have got that wrong. I know that you will use the definite article in situations where we have abandoned it; e.g. you talk of being 'taken to "the" hospital', where we would say 'taken to hospital'. I just had the idea that 'winter,summer etc' would be in that category. I know there are other instances.

Comment: @WS2, you're absolutely right - we still use the definite article in cases of "the hospital", "the university", etc. It's tricky to second-guess the nuances of each others' version of English, isn't it? :-)

Comment: @Kristina Lopez  See my exchange above with Colin Fine. I don't know if he can supply any clue as to why we have dropped the identifier for hospital, university, school etc. Presumably because these are quasi-proper nouns.

Answer (score 0):

> In my opinion, 'the' is a definite article. It emphasis saying "that one only".

You can get into trouble learning a rule of thumb about an article, and then going through life assuming that the word is always used in that way, and in that way only.

When I look up *the* in NOAD, I find **six** definitions. Surely, then, the article has a wider scope than what was initially expressed in your “opinion.” For example, the third definition reads:

> **the** (*article*) used to make a generalized reference to something rather than identifying a particular instance : *he taught himself to play the violin* | *worry about the future*.

I suspect your use of *winter season* might have been similar: *We need to get some firewood before the winter season*. I wouldn't exclude the article in that sentence.

When a word is used by a credible source, and that usage doesn't jibe with your preconceived ideas about that word's meaning, there's a good chance the word can be more widely applied than you initially thought. This seems to be especially true with articles and prepositions, which are mightily flexible little imps.

Answer (score 0):

Winter in ‘the winter season’ is being used as an adjective not a noun. Hence the need for the definite article. ‘The’ refers to season not winter here.